Is it possible to copy an Android app to my PC with its current state?
I've been learning reverse engineering for quite a bit now, and I wanted to develop my skills by putting myself into challenge. I've been solving some CTFs and Crackmes, but I felt like these were made to be reversed, I wanted to try and reverse something that WAS NOT intended to be reversed (Nothing harmful of course).
So there is this game I've been playing called 2048, and unfortunately I got stuck at some point as you can see here

Then it got me thinking, Why wouldn't I reverse the game, and do a little bit of "cheating" by either changing the numbers or giving myself more Undos.
But then I was wondering how can I move the game to my PC with it current state? so I be working on this current game and editing on it? is it even possible? If so, can I as well export the modded version with the same state? Any suggestion on how should I approach this?
NOTE: I clearly realize that this is "cheating" but its totally for learning purposes, and it totally for myself only. its just an offline game and I wanted a "REAL" app to try and develop my Reverse engineering skills
